# How to handle Gesture Arena?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some conflicting gestures and GestureDetector is choosing the "wrong" one. I need to make the ScaleGestureRecognizer the winner of the gestures:

[image: Here is my console]

How can I make the decision manually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of research. Is not recommended to alter how Gesture Arena works. It's better to adapt the code to how Gesture Arena flow works, rather to try to do some workaround.